# Set scene width and height

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

I have been trying to set the scene's width and height outside of the constructor and it's been to no avail. After looking through the `Scene` API I saw a method that lets you get the height and width respectively but not one to set the method.. :s (design flaw maybe).

After further research I came across the `SceneBuilder` and found methods that could modify the height and width. However, I do not know how to apply it to a scene object already created or how to create a `SceneBuilder` object that could be used in place of the scene object.

Answer (score 15):

Once you created `Scene` and assigned it to the `Stage` you can use `Stage.setWidth` and `Stage.setHeight` to change both stage and scene sizes simultaneously.

`SceneBuilder` can't be applied to an already created object, it can only be used for the scene creation.

Comment: Note that this answer is not the same as setting the _Scene_ width or height, because `Stage.setWidth()` and `Stage.setHeight` includes the window's decoration. See @user2229691's answer below if this matters to you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems not possible to set the size of the `Scene` after it has been created.

Setting the size of the `Stage` means to set the size of the window, which includes the size of the decoration. So the `Scene` is smaller in size, unless the `Stage` is undecorated.

My solution is to compute the size of the decoration while initialization and add it to the size of the `Stage` when resizing:

```
private Stage stage;
private double decorationWidth;
private double decorationHeight;

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    this.stage = stage;

    final double initialSceneWidth = 720;
    final double initialSceneHeight = 640;
    final Parent root = createRoot();
    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, initialSceneWidth, initialSceneHeight);

    this.stage.setScene(scene);
    this.stage.show();

    this.decorationWidth = initialSceneWidth - scene.getWidth();
    this.decorationHeight = initialSceneHeight - scene.getHeight();
}

public void resizeScene(double width, double height) {
    this.stage.setWidth(width + this.decorationWidth);
    this.stage.setHeight(height + this.decorationHeight);
}
```

Comment: I think the API has changed a bit since this answer was written. `Scene.getX()` is now always equal to `initialSceneX`, so this answer will always give a decoration size of 0. To get this to work, I had to change the decoration calculation to `stage.getWidth() - initialWidth` and `stage.getHeight() - initialHeight`.

But after that it worked flawlessly! This is exactly the smart solution I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post another answer for those who might have had a similar problem as mine.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html

There is no `setWidth()` or `setHeight()`, and the property is `ReadOnly`, but if you look at

```
Constructors

Scene(Parent root)
Creates a Scene for a specific root Node.

Scene(Parent root, double width, double height)
Creates a Scene for a specific root Node with a specific size.

Scene(Parent root, double width, double height, boolean depthBuffer)
Constructs a scene consisting of a root, with a dimension of width and height, and specifies whether a depth buffer is created for this scene.

Scene(Parent root, double width, double height, boolean depthBuffer, SceneAntialiasing antiAliasing)
Constructs a scene consisting of a root, with a dimension of width and height, specifies whether a depth buffer is created for this scene and specifies whether scene anti-aliasing is requested.

Scene(Parent root, double width, double height, Paint fill)
Creates a Scene for a specific root Node with a specific size and fill.

Scene(Parent root, Paint fill)
Creates a Scene for a specific root Node with a fill.
```

As you can see, this is where you can set the height and width if you need to.

For me, I am using `SceneBuilder`, just as you described you were doing, and needed the width and height of that.  I am creating custom controls, so it was weird that it didn't do it automatically, so this is how to do it if you need to.

I could have used `setWidth()` / `setHeight()` from the `Stage` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar challenge when I wanted to switch between different size scenes in JavaFX.

I did my scene switching by changing the `Parent` resource of a `Scene`. The new resource would have larger dimensions than the previous resource so the entire `Scene` wasn't visible.

Like user2229691's answer stated - my issue turned out to be the Window not matching the `Scene`'s dimensions.

Although I'm not able to comment about decorations - I was able to solve my issue by using:
`sceneName.getWindow().sizeToScene();`

It works when downsizing and upsizing from my own testing.

Here's some example code so you can better understand what I did:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    // Height of 300, width of 300
    Parent scene1 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene1.fxml"));

    // Height of 400, width of 400
    Parent scene2 = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene2.fxml"));
    
    // Starting off in the smaller scene
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(scene1); // Scene & Window are 300x300
    stage.setScene(mainScene);
    stage.show();

    // Switching to the larger scene resource, that doesn't fit in the window
    mainScene.setRoot(scene2); // Scene is 400x400 but can only see 300x300
    
    // Resizing the window so the larger scene fits
    mainScene.getWindow().sizeToScene(); // Window is now 400x400 & everything is visible

}
```

I hope this helps someone.

Source:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene--

Answer (score 0):

Use AnchorPanes and set child nodes inside of said AnchorPanes to your liking then give the nodes of the of the AnchorPanes fx:ids. Go to your controller file and add the following to to where you want to resize the scene:

```
double elementIdNewWidth = 300;
double elementIdNewHeight = 300;
elementId.setPrefWidth(elementIdNewWidth);
elementId.setPrefHeight(elementIdNewHeight);
elementId.autosize();
```

If `elementId` is resizable, then the element will resize to 300 by 300 and the children inside of it will not change.

See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#autosize--

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setPrefWidth(double)

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setPrefHeight(double)